# how to set sample id in QBP^Q11 for QPD segment using java

Tags: java, spring-boot, hl7, hl7-v2

```
QBP_Q11() qbp=new QBP_Q11();
qbp.getQPD().getQpd3_UserParametersInsuccessivefields().setData(data);
```

Comment: question copied from [this link](https://exceptionshub.com/how-to-set-sample-id-in-qbpq11-for-qpd-segment-using-java-2.html)

Comment: go through [HL7 QBP_Q11 Documentation](https://hapifhir.github.io/hapi-hl7v2/v27/apidocs/ca/uhn/hl7v2/model/v27/message/QBP_Q11.html)

Answer (score 0):

Varies varies = updateSampleId(orderDTO.getSampleId(), qbpq11);
        qpdSegment.getQpd3_UserParametersInsuccessivefields().setData(varies);